# AngularJS adding ng-click in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive

I'm implementing drag'n'drop directive. On drop I add a copy of element to my div and append `ng-click` attribute to it like this:

```
copy.append('<button class="close" ng-click="abc()">&times;</button>');
```

For example, in controller I have

```
$scope.abc = function () {
    alert('Hello!');
}
```

And it doesn't work. If I add this button on page manually it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
copy.append('<button class="close" ng-click="abc()">&times;</button>');
$compile(copy)($scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you do need to compile your new template so that AngularJS recognizes it.
The docs give you a good example for how to use [`ng.$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile).

Cloning can be done then like so:

```
var templateHTML = angular.element('<p>{{total}}</p>'),
    scope = ....;

var clonedElement = $compile(templateHTML)(scope, function(clonedElement, scope) {
  //attach the clone to DOM document at the right place
});
```